# Some USB devices work, some don't on Macbook

Tags: macos, leopard

Some older USB devices such as flash drives or mice work on my Macbook 2007 model, but newer ones are not recognized. Any ideas about the diagnosis and the cure?

Comment: Could you be more precise? Which newer ones are not recognized? Can you provide some example (manufacturer, model)?

Comment: Could it be a USB 2 vs. USB 3 issue? Macs only support USB 2.